# jQuery how to specify an existing selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I do a selection on a existing selection in jQuery?
This is the given HTML

```
<div id='search'>
    <form action='' method='GET'>
        <input id="searchbutton" type='submit' name='qs' value='search'>
            <div id="searchoptions">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="search_books book" name="search_books" value="1" /><label for="search_books">book</label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="search_movies movie" name="search_movies" value="1" /><label for="search_movies">movies</label>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The jQuery part:

```
$('#search').each(function(){
    //do stuff
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert('checkbox clicked');
    });
});
```

Of curse the click function triggers if the div gets clicked.
But I'd like it to get triggered if the checkbox is clicked.
I could just do
    $('#search input:checkbox')
but I need to do some stuff with #search first.
So how to I append a selector to $(this)?

e.g. $(this'input:checkbox')

Sorry if it's a fools question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in this case, for example:

```
$(this).find(':checkbox');
//equiavlent to $('#search :checkbox')
```

There are many other [tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) like this as well.

You can also do: `$(':checkbox', this)` but that's really just converted to the above by jQuery under the covers, so better to do it yourself IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

On another note, there's no reason to use `.each()` on `$('#search')` because that selector will only ever return 1 element, since HTML element IDs must be unique.

Comment: I have to disagree that the `.each()` usage has anything to do with how many elements the set has.  In fact it's not really related IMO, since `.bind()` (or pretty much any function) works on multiple elements, but even in a single element you may still want/need a `.each()`, for example:  `$("#ID").each(function() { $(this).plugin({text: this.href}); });`

Comment: I think the reason that the OP is using each() is because as he says "...I need to do some stuff with #search first", and that was their way of putting it into scope. But you are correct, each on an ID selector is usually not really needed.

Comment: thanks for that note.
What should I write instead of .each() ?
Sorry but I started coding with jQuery today and I try to follow some tutorials but I have some difficulties understanding the chained-function-concept.
I actually understand how it's done but thinking this way is hard.

Comment: If you want to bind a click listener to the div with ID `search`, just write `$('#search').click(function () { /* whatever */ } );`

Comment: if you are looking to do lots of things with search and can't get the chaining right, you could put it into a self calling function: <code>(function(x){
  //x will refer to $("#search");
})($("#search"));</code> But whether this is a good idea someone else will tell you :)

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific.
There're multiple checkboxes that are preselected to checked.
If a checkbox gets unchecked a ajax call should be executed sending every checked checkbox to a script.
In my mind this is done by (pseudocode):
checkbox gets clicked:
 -> get all checked checkboxes
 -> ajax call
and it seems weird to $(':checkbox').click(function(){}) and in there go one level up to check all checkboxes which are checked or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to open a new question regarding this issue. At any rate, you can listen for `change` (not `click`) events on the parent since the event will bubble up from checkbox that fired it. Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/): `$('#search').live('change', function (event) { /* your ajax logic here */ });`

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable to contain your result set.

```
var $myVar = $('#search');
```

Then use the .add() method.

```
$myVar = $myVar.add($('#search input:checkbox'));
$myVar.click(function(){
    alert('div or checkbox clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(":checkbox", $(this));
```

where the second parameter is the context on which to search for elements which match the selector.

So

```
$(":checkbox", $(this)).click(function(){
    alert('checkbox clicked');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use your parent() and children() methods.  You can specify selectors as arguments.

```
$(this).children(':checkbox');
```

Comment: Using `.children()` won't work in this situation because it only looks at immediate descendants. To look deeper, you need `.find()`.